# From finite addivity to countable additivity. Why is the below fact sufficient?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let us pretend we have a field called $\mathscr{R}_0$ and a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ which is finitely addivitive on it. Suppose that there is a sequence of events $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $A_n\in\mathscr{R}_0\text{ all }n$.
I quote *Billingsley (1995)*:

> We would like to show that $\mathbb{P}$ is also countably additive on $\mathscr{R}_0$ and this will follow if, starting from a sequence $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, $A_n\in\mathscr{R}_0$ and $A_n\downarrow \emptyset$ together imply $\mathbb{P}(A_n)\downarrow 0$. 
> Suppose that $A_1\supset A_2\supset\cdots$ and that $\mathbb{P}(A_n)\geq\varepsilon>0$ for all $n$.
> $\color{red}{\text{The problem is to show that }\bigcap_{n} A_n \text{ must be nonempty.}}$

---

My question revolves around the $\color{red}{\text{ red part}}$ immediately above.
Since $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a decreasing sequence of events, I know that:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\tag{1}$$
Since, as stated in my reference, we know that:
$$A_n\in\mathscr{R}_0\hspace{0.4cm}\text{ and }\hspace{0.4cm} A_n\downarrow \emptyset\implies \mathbb{P}(A_n)\downarrow0\tag{2}$$
I would like to have that:

1. $A_n\in\mathscr{R}_0$;
2. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n=\emptyset$, that is, equivalently, $A_n\downarrow\emptyset$;

Condition $1.$ is satisfied by assumption, while for condition $2.$ to be fulfilled I would expect that I have to show that:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=\emptyset\tag{3}$$
and not that *"$\bigcap_n A_n$ is nonempty"*.

---

---

So, why does it suffice to show that *"$\bigcap_n A_n$ is nonempty"* in order for $(2)$ to hold true, if one of the condition required for that result is precisely that $A_n\downarrow\emptyset$?

Comment: You seem to be saying we already know $$A_n\downarrow \emptyset \implies \mathbb{P}(A_n)\downarrow 0$$ but this implication is what we're trying to prove.

Comment: $A_n$ tends to $0$, not to the empty set. We are taking the result $(2)$ for granted. We just seek to ensure that one of the conditions for $(2)$ to hold true (namely, $A_n\to 0$) is satisfied @BrianMoehring

Comment: I'm not sure what the event $0$ is.  In any case, since $\mathbb{P}$ is finitely additive, we can just replace $A_n$ with $A_n\setminus 0$.  Also, if you are taking (2) for granted, there is nothing to show.  You already have a countably additive probability measure.

Comment: You are confusing the events with the random variables themselves. They are not the same. $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of EVENTS.

Comment: Sorry, you are perfectly right. I edit @TSF

Comment: So now it should make sense why $A_n$ converges to the empty set and not $0$. $0$ is not an event. Reread what you've written now, distinguishing between random variables and events

Comment: So, just for example, $A_n\downarrow\frac{1}{3}$ does not make sense as well, since $\frac{1}{3}$ is not an event, right? @TSF

Comment: Right. Each $A_n$ is a set.

Comment: If Billingsley actually said $A_n \downarrow 0$ then it was an error.  It should be $A_n \downarrow \varnothing$.  You didn't provide the page number, so I didn't try to look it up in my copy.

Comment: Yeah, it is a typo there I guess @GEdgar

Comment: Of course, since an event is a set of outcomes, thank you a lot for helping me get to the point @TSF

Comment: Of course, it's a pleasure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fintely additive probability measure $P$ is countably additive if and only if  $P(A_n) \to 0$ whenever $A_n$ decreases to empty set. Suppose there is  sequence $A_n$ decreasing to empty set such that $P(A_n)$ does not tend to $0$. Since $P(A_n)$ is decreasing it follows that $\epsilon =\inf P(A_n) >0$. So we have $P(A_n) \geq \epsilon$ for all $n$. We can get a contradiction by showing that $\bigcap A_n$ must be empty.

Comment: In my reference it is stated that one of the condition for $\mathbb{P}(A_n)\downarrow0$ to be true is that $$An\downarrow0$$
and not that $$A_n\downarrow\emptyset$$

Comment: $A_n $ decreasing to $0$ must be typo. Read is as $A_n$ decreasing to empty set. @Strictly_increasing

Comment: If there is a typo, all fine. Could you please give me a reference showing the result with $A_n\downarrow\emptyset$? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Pardon, just one last observation: so, if I assume that $\cap A_n=\emptyset$, why couldn't it happen that $P(A_n)\geq \varepsilon>0$? For example, I 
could think of some sets whose intersection is empty, but every set has an associated probability which is bigger than or equal to $\varepsilon$ @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @Strictly_increasing We are trying to show that $P(A_n) \to 0$. If this is not true then we  get $P(A_n) \geq \epsilon$ for all $n$. And then  we arrive at a contradiction by showing that $\cap A_n$ is non-empty.

Comment: Yeah, the logic was already pretty clear in general. The strange fact to me (*I'm sure it's a silly error of mine*) is that, in the very last passage, it seems to me that you are stating that  $$P(A_n)\geq\varepsilon\text{ for all }n\implies\cap_n A_n\ne\emptyset$$ However, I was thinking: why should that fact be true? Couldn't there happen that even if $P(A_n)\geq\varepsilon>0\text{ (for all }n\text{)}$, $\cap_n A_n = \emptyset$? That is..even if each of the set $A_n$ has a positive probability associated to itself, the intersection of all the considered sets $A_n$ is empty? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @Strictly_increasing That can happen for finitely additive $P$ but it cannot happen for countable additive $P$. It would contradict countable additivity.

Comment: But that $P$ is countably additive is what we are trying to show, not our starting point, I guess. So, how could you take advantage of countable additivity nature of $P$ in your very last passage? Apart from that, which is the reason why the fact I am pointing at in my example could happen only for finitely additive $P$? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @Strictly_increasing I tried to explain the red part. What happens after that in BiIlingsley's book I do not know.